# Division and Mod with negative numbers

Tags: c++, math

I'm trying to solve a [contest problem](http://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/repository/UOJ_1837_en.html) that was supposed to be simple.

What is the result of the quotient **q** and remainder **r** for 2 numbers **a** and **b** (-1.000 ≤ a, b < 1.000)?

The input consist of 2 numbers **a** and **b**.

Example of 3 different inputs:
7 3
7 -3
-7 3

The output is the quotient **q** followed by the remainder **r** of the division of **a** by **b**.

Example of output:
2 1
-2 1
-3 2

My code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);

    int r = 0;
    if(a > 0)
        r = a%b;
    if(a < 0)
        r = (a%b + b)%b;


    printf("%d %d\n",(a-r)/b,r);
}
```

My solution is wrong in 10% of the test cases and i don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it doesn't follow the specifications when b is negative.

a%b is the same as a%(-b) in some implementations of C++. (Thanks to DarioOO for clarifying this. See DarioOO's comment.) Suppose that is the case here. Your code

```
if(a < 0)
    r = (a%b + b)%b;
```

assumes that b is positive. If b=-3 and a=-7, then a%b is -1, and your code assigns r=(-4)%(-3) which is -1. You are supposed to produce a nonnegative remainder, 2. If b<0, you want

```
if(a < 0)
    r = (a%b - b)%b;
```

instead.

Comment: To be clear, the sign is specified when negative numbers are involved only in C++11, in C++ `a%b` may yield both a positive or a negative number if one or both of the operands are negative(`a%b` is NOT the same of `a%(-b)` it is implementation dependent, unless you enable c++11 or you implement your own modulus function).